# Correct behavior using virtual methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Suppose I have a pure virtual method in the `base` interface that returns to me a list of `something`:

```
class base 
{ 
public:
     virtual std::list<something> get() = 0; 
};
```

Suppose I have two classes that inherit the `base` class:

```
class A : public base 
{ 
public:
     std::list<something> get();
}; 

class B : public base 
{ 
public:
     std::list<something> get(); 
};
```

I want that only the `A` class can return a `list<something>`, but I need also to have the possibility to get the list using a `base` pointer, like  for example:

```
base* base_ptr = new A();
base_ptr->get();
```

What I have to do?

Have I to return a pointer to this list? A reference?

Have I to return a null pointer from the method of class `B`? Or have I to throw an exception when I try to get the list using a `B` object? Or have I to change the `base` class method `get`, making it not pure and do this work in the `base` class?

Have I to do something else?

Comment: If it is only specific to `class A` shouldn't it be in `class A` only and not in `Base`?

Comment: @Naveen yes but, as i wrote, I need the possibility to get the list using a pointer to the `base` class.

Comment: @Nick Then probably `class B` should not be a subclass of `Base`. Something might be broken in the design.

Comment: Why? If you have a pointer to a `base`, you could always cast it to `A *`, either using `static_cast` or using `dynamic_cast` depending on whether you know the concrete type. (Edit: changed `A` to `A *`.)

Comment: @betabandido I can't, I need also the possibility to store `A` and `B` object for example in the same list.

Comment: @hvd I prefer don't cast anything, I want to use virtual function.

Comment: Again, why? You want to use a virtual function when there is no apparent sense to use a virtual function, so it would really help if you explain further.

Comment: The design is at fault here. If you're having to rely on an implicit knowedge of which concrete type a base class pointer is pointing at so that you can cast it, you may as well not pass the base class pointer about because you've already lost the benefits of polymorphism. In this case, `B` is clearly not a `base` conceptually, so shouldn't be derived from `base`.

Comment: @hvd More info? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344530/how-to-design-my-class) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335738/create-stdlist-of-value-instead-of-stdlist-of-pointers-in-recursive-function) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335457/fast-way-to-convert-stdlist-of-pointer-to-stdlist-of-value).

Comment: Meyers item 32: `Make sure public inheritance models "is-a"`. *Everything* that is true for the base class should be true for the derived class. If `B` really is-a `Base` and calling `get()` on `B` is invalid, then calling `get()` on `Base` should be invalid.

Comment: @BoBTFish Good, can I have a reference?

Comment: @Nick If I read those other questions right, the only reason you have a base class is to be able to store `A` and `B` in the same list. And I suppose what you're doing now is iterating over a list (meaning you get a `base *`), and try to call `get()`? What do you want to have happen when your list contains `B` objects?

Comment: @hvd yes, you understood correctly. `B` is simply a type of object that has something in common with `A`, but not all. Can you better rephrase your question?

Comment: @Nick What I mean is, `B::get()` isn't supposed to work, your list may contain `B` objects, and you don't want to check whether the object is an `A` object (`dynamic_cast`), so what do you want `base->get()` to do when `base` points to a `B` object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have nothing else to do. The code you provide does exactly that.

When you get a pointer to the base class, since the method was declared in the base class, and is virtual, the actual implementation will be looked up in the class virtual function table and called appropriately.

So

```
base* base_ptr = new A();
base_ptr->get();
```

Will call A::get(). You should not return null from the implementation (well you can't, since null is not convertible to std::list< something > anyway). You have to provide an implementation in A/B since the base class method is declared pure virtual.

**EDIT**:

you cannot have only A return an std::list< something > and not B since B also inherits the base class, and the base class has a pure virtual method that *must* be overriden in the derived class. Inheriting from a base class is a "is-a" relationship. The only other way around I could see would be to inherit privately from the class, but that would prevent derived to base conversion.

If you really don't want B to have the get method, don't inherit from base.
Some alternatives are:

**Throwing an exception in B::get():**
You could throw an exception in B::get() but make sure you explain your rationale well as it is counter-intuitive. IMHO this is pretty bad design, and you risk confusing people using your base class. It is a leaky abstraction and is best avoided.

**Separate interface:**
You could break base into separate interface for that matter:

```
class IGetSomething
{
public:
    virtual ~IGetSomething() {}
    virtual std::list<something> Get() = 0;
};

class base
{
public:
    // ...
};

class A : public base, public IGetSomething
{
public:
    virtual std::list<something> Get()
    {
        // Implementation
        return std::list<something>();
    }
};

class B : public base
{

};
```

The multiple inheritance in that case is OK because IGetSomething is a pure interface (it does not have member variables or non-pure methods).

**EDIT2**:

Based on the comments it seems you want to be able to have a common interface between the two classes, yet be able to perform some operation that one implementation do, but the other doesn't provide. It is quite a convoluted scenario but we can take inspiration from COM (don't shoot me yet):

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual ~base() {}
    // ... common interface

    // TODO: give me a better name
    virtual IGetSomething *GetSomething() = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    virtual IGetSomething *GetSomething()
    {
        return NULL;
    }
};

class B : public Base, public IGetSomething
{
public:
    virtual IGetSomething *GetSomething()
    {
        // Derived-to-base conversion OK
        return this;
    }
};
```

Now what you can do is this:

```
base* base_ptr = new A();
IGetSomething *getSmthing = base_ptr->GetSomething();
if (getSmthing != NULL)
{
    std::list<something> listOfSmthing = getSmthing->Get();
}
```

It is convoluted, but there are several advantages of this method:

- You return public interfaces, not concrete implementation classes.
- You use inheritance for what it's designed for.
- It is hard to use mistakenly: base does not provide std::list get() because it is not a common operation between the concrete implementation.
- You are explicit about the semantics of GetSomething(): it allows you to return an interface that can be use to retrieve a list of something.

  > What about just returning an empty std::list ?

That would be possible but bad design, it's like having a vending machine that can give Coke and Pepsi, except it never serves Pepsi; it's misleading and best avoided.

> What about just returning a boost::optional< std::list< something > > ? (as suggested by Andrew)

I think that's a better solution, better than returning and interface that sometimes could be NULL and sometimes not, because then you explicitly know that it's optional, and there would be no mistake about it.

The downside is that it puts boost inside your interface, which I prefer to avoid (it's up to me to use boost, but clients of the interface shouldn't have to be forced to use boost).

Comment: Ok, but if I write `base* base_ptr = new B();` what is the behavior of `base_ptr->get();` ?

Comment: I believe the OP's asking "How can I avoid having to provide an implementation in B(), but still be able to call A::get() from the base class pointer."

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect that. In short, the behavior is the same. Since you inherit the base class, you must implement its pure virtual functions.

Comment: @LeSnip3R razlebe explains what i'm asking, what I have to return using `B::get()`?

Comment: When you say `If you really don't want B to have the get method, don't inherit from base.` you don't understand my question, but the idea of `IGetSomething` could be good, thus +1

Comment: Anyway remeber that in this way I can't do this: `base_ptr->get()`. So this is not what I want.

Comment: You would have to expand you question then to explain this better. I will add a third alternative to my answer that might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

return `boost::optional` in case you need an ability to not return (in B class)

```
class base 
{ 
public:
     virtual boost::optional<std::list<something> > get() = 0; 
};
```

Comment: I like that, except for the fact that it puts boost in a base class. I have nothing against boost, but I avoid forcing clients of the interface to use it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is wrong. If it is not common to both the derived classes, you should probably not have it in the base class.

That aside, there is no way to achieve what you want. You have to implement  the method in B also - which is precisely the meaning of a pure virtual function. However, you can add a special fail case - such as returning an empty list, or a list with one element containing a predetermined invalid value.